# Same question, I expect a different answer

Tags: support

I have a question, and I found out that the same question was asked, and there is a perfectly suitable answer there.

However, I am looking for a different answer (I am 100% sure that it exists). Should I ask a different question, or just beg for a different answer in a comment to the first question? How would I decide the correct answer for my question / answer?

Update: It is not about what I like or not. I am looking to find another film with the "exact" same story (or, at least, very similar). Possibly a re-make, or the original of a re-make.

Comment: Without context, it's hard to be sure what you mean. Is the "perfectly suitable" answer wrong? If it's right, why do you want "a different answer"?

Comment: If you re-post exactly the same question, it will be closed as a duplicate. If you post saying you're looking for a different answer to the one already posted, then it very much depends on context. E.g. if question A asks for examples of X, and its answer gives one example Q, then you might get away with asking question B as "are there any examples of X other than Q?" But if question A asks something where answer Q is given and you just disagree with it, then question B asking "can I have another answer to question A?" would likely be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your edit it seems you are looking to ask a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question. In this case the question you have found has an answer but it is not the work you are looking for. With [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions being somewhat of a special case on the site then this means that by definition this question is not a duplicate because you are looking for a different work.

What I would recommend you do is write up your own question in your own words and also link to the other question saying you saw that and it's similar but the answer given is not what you're looking for.

Comment: In the meanwhile I succeeded to clarify my "confusion". Thank you, though. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/273924/blind-people-take-revenge-against-evil-asylum-manager/273925#273925